# LDAP Configuration Laravel5 - Authentication user provider [adldap] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, ldap, laravel-5.8

I'm fresh beginner in Laravel 5.8 and i'm trying to develop an app with LDAP authentication.

I use this package : https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2-Laravel/#/auth/setup

So, here is my configuration code **(app.php)** :

```php
// service providers array
Adldap\Laravel\AdldapServiceProvider::class,
Adldap\Laravel\AdldapAuthServiceProvider::class

// aliases array
'Adldap' => Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap::class
```

The LDAP configuration **(ldap.php)** :

```
'hosts' => explode(' ', env('LDAP_HOSTS', 'myserver1 myserver2'))
'port' => env('LDAP_PORT', 389),
'base_dn' => env('LDAP_BASE_DN', 'dc=mydc1,dc=mydc2,dc=mydc3'),
'username' => env('admin'),
'password' => env('admin'),
```

The authentication configuration **(auth.php)** :

```php
// user provider fields
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'adldap',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],
```

And then the UserController:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Adldap\AdldapInterface;

class UserController extends Controller
{

    protected $ldap;


    public function __construct(AdldapInterface $ldap) {
        $this->ldap = $ldap;
    }

    public function index() {
        $users = $this->ldap->search()->users()->get();
        return view('users.index',compact('users'));
    }
}
```

And i got this error : **Authentication user provider [adldap] is not defined.**
Does anyone know this error and could tell me where my configuration can be wrong ?

Thansk for your help :)

EDIT : Idk if this could help but this morning the error precise me that the problem is in the **welcome.blade.php file**

Comment: You have provided basically no information. Perhaps your filter is wrong when searching for the user.

Comment: i did not want to put all the config code for better reading purpose but i'm going to edit my post

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some basic configuration in your .env file

```
ACCOUNT_PREFIX = local
ACCOUNT_SUFFIX = local
DOMAIN_CONTROLLERS = "172.16.20.142"
PORT = 389
TIMEOUT = 5
BASE_DN = "dc=local,dc=local"
USER_DN = "cn=users,dc=dummy,dc=local"
ADMIN_ACCOUNT_SUFFIX = @man.local
ADMIN_USERNAME = administrator
ADMIN_PASSWORD = dsds
LDAP_USER_CUSTOM_EMAIL_DOMAIN = @man.local
```

and check your aldap.config once

after that please clear cache of config  by following command

```
php artisan config:clear && php artisan cache:clear &&  php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear  && php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: i don't have my config in the .env i put it in the ldap.php file like in the documentation of the package (https://adldap2.github.io/Adldap2/#/setup?id=options) idk if this is a mistake or not

Comment: add lines which i added in your .env  so the configuration in .env will overwrite with your aldap.php file

Comment: I recently done implementation aldap with same library u used and used  Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap; at top of my class where i want to use

Comment: $users = Adldap::getDefaultProvider()->search()->users()->get(); is worked for me

Comment: Also you have error in configuration 

'username' => 'admin',
'password' => 'admin',

Comment: idk why but still not working, i'm gonna ask to the IT administrator the config because i think the problem is here

Comment: i put fake value for the username & the password

Comment: If u putting fake user name and password this will not work so please co ordinate with IT team and get correct credentials and congifuration

Comment: after that it will help you

Comment: no i just change them for the publication ahah :) i put the correct one i'm my config